# Convert int to UIntPtr in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, integer

Thanks in advance.

In the following piece of simple code, the model.Count is an `System.Int32` integer which I get from the a third party library named [Xilium.CefGlue](https://gitlab.com/xiliumhq/chromiumembedded/cefglue/-/blob/main/CefGlue/Classes.Proxies/CefMenuModel.cs) (v107). I iterate over this integer to get the value based on the index.

```
 indexCollection = cefMenuModel.Count;
 for(int x=0;x<indexCollection;x++)
 {
   var value = GetCommandIdAt(x); 
 }
```

In the latest version of CefGlue library, The `cefMenuModel.Count` value has been changed from `System.Int32` integer to `UIntPtr` and since then I am finding type conversion and '<' operator cannot be applied on `UIntPtr` compile time error messages.

The `GetCommandIdAt(x)` in the older version of C++ library took parameter as an integer but now in the latest version it is expecting the parameter as `UIntPtr`.

What change can I make in my above piece code to change the int type to `UIntPtr`. Basically I want to iterate over a collection of `UIntPtr` that I receive from `cefMenuModel.Count` and pass that `UIntPtr` value to `GetCommandIdAt(x)` ?

The Xelium.CefGlue expects the GetCommandIdAt as:

```
 namespace Xilium.CefGlue
{
    
    [NullableAttribute(0)]
    [NullableContextAttribute(1)]
    public sealed class CefMenuModel : IDisposable
    {
        ~CefMenuModel();

        //
        // Summary:
        // Returns the number of items in this menu.
        [NativeIntegerAttribute]
        public UIntPtr Count { get; }
       
        // Summary:
        // Returns the command id at the specified |index| or -1 if not found due to invalid
        // range or the index being a separator.
        public int GetCommandIdAt([NativeIntegerAttribute] UIntPtr index);
    
     }
}
```

Comment: It's really bad breaking an interface like that! They should have kept the old interface and introduced a new differently-named function instead. Anyway, is the `UIntPtr` being used as an index or as a pointer now? It's documented, right?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Yes, I agree ! The UIntPtr is being used as an index. It is documented in the assembly. I have updated my question with documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `UIntPtr` values will be in the range of a 32-bit integer (which I assume they must be, because you can't address more than 2^31 items in an array in C#), then you can just freely cast between a `UIntPtr` and an `int`:

```
UIntPtr uip1 = new UIntPtr(34234);

Console.WriteLine(uip1); // 34234
        
int i = (int) uip1;  // Cast from UIntPtr to int

Console.WriteLine(i); // 34234

UIntPtr uip2 = (UIntPtr) i;

Console.WriteLine(uip2); // 34234
```

Also note that you can now use the [`nuint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nuint?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) type instead of `UIntPtr` and the [`nint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nint?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) type instead of `IntPtr`:

```
nuint uip1 = 34234;

Console.WriteLine(uip1); // 34234
        
int i = (int) uip1;  // Cast from nuint to int

Console.WriteLine(i); // 34234

nuint uip2 = (nuint) i;

Console.WriteLine(uip2); // 34234
```

IMPORTANT:

It's totally weird that the authors of the library would make this change. The size of a `UIntPtr` (and `nuint`) is 64 bits when running as x64 and 32 bits when running as x86. This means that casting to `int` will fail on an x64 build if the value exceeds 2^31.

As I said earlier, a value of greater than 2^31 is NOT supported for array or list indexing in C#, so if it exceeds that value you're stuffed either way.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Watson, What is 34234 here, Is it a sample integer value you've taken as example ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a random number for illustration.

Comment: @Mattew Watson : Thank you so much, your answer with example was very helpful.